# Pull source from Production Org to Scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx

Can I pull the full source code from production org to scratch org, so that I can store these in Repository for the future work and also deploy code via continuous integration. I have started Salesforce just 4 weeks earlier and I am a .NET developer by profession. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can. Where specifically are you stuck? How can we assist you moving forward? You'll want to read about [ask] and take the [tour] to get an idea of what kind of questions we expect here. Thanks for joining our community, and I hope you have a pleasant experience here!

Comment: [SFDX convert](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/org-development-model) would be a great starting point

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/ to automatically build the package.xml corresponding to your production org.

Then use sfdx [force:mdapi:convert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_convert_mdapi.htm) to convert metatada into SFDX format

Then create a scratch org from your sfdx project